# Enable https (certbot) with new domain, apache

Tags: apache, https, certbot

I have added a domain.

Want to enable https for the new domain with certbot.

Following this https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntubionic-apache

```
sudo certbot --apache
[sudo] password for qq: 
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator apache, Installer apache

Which names would you like to activate HTTPS for?
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
1: old.example.com
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Select the appropriate numbers separated by commas and/or spaces, or leave input
blank to select all options shown (Enter 'c' to cancel):
```

I can only see my old domain. I have ssh via the new domain.

How do I add the new domain?

Comment: Do you have new host resolver and configured in apache?

Comment: @RomeoNinov I don't know. Where is this setting?

Comment: What is your host OS, how do you install apache? How do you configure it?

Comment: Ubuntu. I used apt-get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you forgot to add the domain in your Apache configs. Try to look through your configs at `/etc/apache2/sites-available`.

If your new domain name have been configured already, try to see if it have been enabled by checking if the config file is linked in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`. If it is, try to reload apache2 to ensure the latest configs are loaded

```sh
sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

Or if the configs weren't there, try to enable them

```sh
sudo a2ensite my-new-config
sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

If the new domain still doesn't show up, you could try to generate the certificate manually, and then manually using it in your configs:

```sh
sudo certbot certonly -d new-domain.com -d www.new-domain.com
```

Comment: Where do I specify new domain? There's 3 files under sites-available. Is it 000-default.conf. In this file I have RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =old.example.com

Comment: @Joe You can set the `ServerName` and (if needed) `ServerAlias` inside the virtual host https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html

Comment: Yes. I have the old domain under ServerName. But it's comment out (#ServerName)?

Comment: You need to have the `ServerName` set. If you want to enable both the old and the new, then you can have the correct one in `ServerName` and the other(s) in `ServerAlias` i.e.
`ServerName www.new-domain.com`

`ServerAlias new-comain.com old-domain.com www.old-domain.com` (`ServerName` and `ServerAlias` on each own line - line breaks aren't shown in comments apparently)